# NSF Abstracts Dataset Update

Tags: data-request, data.gov

We're looking to analyze data from the last five years similar to the [NSF Research Abstracts](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/NSF+Research+Award+Abstracts+1990-2003)

Is there an updated dataset that covers a time after 2003? Are there other text datasets relevant to NSF grants, or research funded by the NSF?

data.gov has some data, but it doesn't seem like they have any text data describing proposals/grants from this period. Even a link to a website that we can scrape would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSF puts all their grant data on the web, and for a given year you can download the zipped file at the following URL:

https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/download?DownloadFileName=YOURYEAR&All=true